# MICE pooling glm - error for some models, but not others from same data set

Tags: glm, r-mice

I have imputed data with MICE (and then summed together some columns together as 'compound measures' - just doing this on some simulated data for now). I try to now run regressions and pool the results. All models have the same predictors, but different predicted values. Strangely this works for some, but not all models. I can't see any obvious differences between the columns for which it works or doesn't work. I'm not sure how to trouble-shoot this.

Here is the code for the two models:

```
df=list2milist(imputed.withPredictions)

fit.somatic.anxiety=with(df,glm(sticsa.trait.somatic.predicted.H2B ~ group+Age+Gender+Education,family='gaussian'))
fit.somatic.anxiety.pooled <- pool_glm(fit.somatic.anxiety)
fit.somatic.anxiety.pooled$pmodel

fit.shaps = with(df,glm(shaps.predicted.H3Bi ~ group+Age+Gender+Education,family='gaussian'))
fit.shaps.pooled=pool_glm(fit.shaps)
```

For fit.somatic.anxiety.pooled, the code runs and I can extract a summary. For fit.shaps.pooled, I get the error with traceback:

```
Error when running pool_glm(fit.shaps):
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  object 'shaps.predicted.H3Bi' not found

traceback()
10: eval(predvars, data, env)
9: eval(predvars, data, env)
8: model.frame.default(formula = form1, data = imp.dt[[i]], drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
7: stats::model.frame(formula = form1, data = imp.dt[[i]], drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
6: eval(mf, parent.frame())
5: eval(mf, parent.frame())
4: glm(form1, data = imp.dt[[i]])
3: glm_lm_bw(data = data, nimp = nimp, impvar = impvar, Outcome = Outcome, 
       P = P, p.crit = p.crit, method = method, keep.P = keep.P)
2: glm_mi(data = imp_dat, formula = fm, p.crit = p.crit, direction = direction, 
       nimp = nimp, impvar = "imp_id", keep.predictors = keep.predictors, 
       method = method, model_type = "linear")
1: pool_glm(fit.shaps)
```

What I have tried:
[1] I have compared the data (e.g. df$Imputation_1$shapspredicted.H3Bi and df$Imputation_1$sticsa.trait.somatic.predicted.H2B) and for all imputations they look similar - i.e. no NAN values and the correlations of these values across the imputations are similar (roughly r=0.96)
[2] I have checked the  output of the with(...) commands, and they look similar (just showing for the first imputations, others also looked similar):

```
$statistics
$statistics[[1]]

Call:  glm(formula = sticsa.trait.somatic.predicted.H2B ~ group + Age + 
    Gender + Education, family = "gaussian")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        group          Age       Gender    Education  
   -0.16961     -0.03702     -0.02191      0.11369      0.01292  

Degrees of Freedom: 51 Total (i.e. Null);  47 Residual
Null Deviance:      1.946 
Residual Deviance: 1.707    AIC: -18.07


> fit.shaps
$call
with.milist(data = df, expr = glm(shaps.predicted.H3Bi ~ group + 
    Age + Gender + Education, family = "gaussian"))

$statistics
$statistics[[1]]

Call:  glm(formula = shaps.predicted.H3Bi ~ group + Age + Gender + Education, 
    family = "gaussian")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        group          Age       Gender    Education  
 -1.486e-01    5.611e-03   -2.360e-02   -6.384e-03    5.231e-05  

Degrees of Freedom: 51 Total (i.e. Null);  47 Residual
Null Deviance:      0.8112 
Residual Deviance: 0.7794   AIC: -58.85
```

Comment: Ok, I think I have tracked it down further. I went into the package function for pool_glm and it turns out for some reason when it creates imp_dat, it changes the names of the columns. Will check further and update here when fixed.

Comment: turns out their function clean_P does something bad to the names. I will file as a bug and for now simplify my variable names.

Answer (score 1):

The pool_glm function comes from the miceafter package (that I developed). In the formula object you have to provide unique variable names and not names that are combinations with numbers as, age2, gender10. I will include a message about that in the update. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful for other people: I think clean_P, which is part of the mice package makes a mistake when doing the column names. I'll file a bug. Work around: manually change your column names to something simpler.